# Postgresql push uuid field to Clickhouse data type error

Tags: postgresql, clickhouse

I am trying to push data from PG-12 to Clickhouse via FDW extension ("clickhouse_fdw") and it gives me error:

> SQL Error [HV004]: ERROR: cannot convert constant value to clickhouse
> value   Hint: Constant value data type: 2950

Sherlocking gave me error in uuid, excepting this field passes on to data transfer. If I cast it to text it gives error, that target field is uuid not text. I am confused. Which data type casting is appropriate here? Please advise DB gurus :) Thanks beforehands.

Comment: open an FR against https://github.com/adjust/clickhouse_fdw/issues

Comment: I did, but these guys never hurry. Had to solve it temporarily via modifying uuid to text in target table. Everything works, but it's not what is required.

Comment: then probably you can use Null table + MV

Comment: Please elaborate, what is "Null table +MV"?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/den-crane/739a51afc304910bb3d81fe6751701ff

Comment: thanks got it, but it's a lot of hassle creating views for the task. Still both ways are not the solution unfortunately, hoping to hearing from clickhouse_fdw soon...